# Signal Protocol - Counter over TCP?

Tags: key-derivation, signal-protocol

[Signal Protocol](https://signal.org/docs/) uses a [counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_(digital)) (discussed in [DoubleRatchet](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) documentation) to define how many times [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) has derived a new key (aka a KDF step) which is then sent along with every message for the end client to know how many derivations (steps) he has to do to obtain a decryption key matching the message key which encrypted the message.

Note: it is also used for creating a message [mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) which is later compared for verification, but since both clients are keeping track of the current counter it should match as long as the order is intact.

This makes sense for protocols that don't have order, but if I am using [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) which keeps order does sending the counter and skipping over messages has any use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing TCP packets and Signal messages.

First, TCP ensures the order of packets inside a session. TCP does not ensure the order among sessions. This means that TCP cannot be used to ensure that the Signal messages are received in the order they were sent.

Also, TCP was not build to resit active tempering by a MITM agent, unlike Signal. It would be extremely unwise for Signal to assume that the properties of TCP are reliable.

Moreover, the end client might not keep track of the previous messages: they could be deleted or the client could have been reinstalled on another device (while keeping the secret keys).

Comment: I didn't mean the TCP counter, I meant the current counter of the KDF, I do increment per message but the question is what do I gain from transmitting it on an ordered protocol? Since an ordered protocol will send messages always incremented by 1 counter (counter + 1 per message)

Comment: @OughtToPrevail Sorry, I did not correctly understand your question at first. I changed my answer.

Comment: I still don't understand your answer, what sessions are involved? it's only 1 TCP session, a client and a server, the server is the one who spreads the messages to the devices, also if the client have been reinstalled on another device with the exact same keys, he should have installed the exact same counter which is stored aswell

Comment: 2 Signal messages can be sent over the same TCP session (very unlikely) or two different TCP sessions (very likely). TCP sessions are short-lived, they last only a few minutes after the last sent packet. They can also be arbitrary cut at any moment in case of an overload of the network.

Comment: Also, the Signal app is free to open a new TCP session per message, even if a TCP session is still in use.

Comment: Oh I understand now, you mean that Signal will close a communication then open a new one, send a message and the new communication message will arrive before the message in the closed communication. Thank you!

Comment: @A.Hersean, Any pointer to the fact that tcp connections are short lived in a messaging app like signal? It would seem quite inefficient. I could see it being done for media data but the overhead is non-negligible for normal messages. You would need at around $2n$ RTTs for sending $n$ messages. Seems like a lot a with the risk of reordering. While a long lived session would require around $n$ RTTs and give you synchronization for "free".

Comment: The TCP stack is not managed by Signal, but by the operating system (typically the Linux kernel for the Android app). The duration of a TCP session depends on the configuration of both endpoints. I'm not sure that an RFC exists that specify the minimum duration of a TCP session.